# Saving several ID's to one jQuery cookie and retrieving all values later

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I'm building an image gallery on WordPress and  I want to add a save to lightbox or save to collection function so that I can collect images with a click of a button and then download all images as a zip later. It sorta like a shopping cart without actually buying the stuff that you want. I want it just to be a per session kind of thing so that you don't need to register to the site.

So on my images page, I put a Save to lightbox button and I want to save the ID of this image to a cookie and then I keep adding images to it until I'm done and will click a view lightbox button that will list all of my collected images.

I know how to set a cookie but I don't know how to append values to it.

```
    function saveLightbox(ID){
      $.cookie('the_cookie', ID, { expires: 7 });
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = $.cookie('the_cookie');
    }
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/g8XgZ/2/)  of roughly how I want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append values to the jQuery cookie, first of all you have to enable the storage of objects. Then you initialize a variable holding the content of the cookie. If the cookie is empty then initialize an empty array. Next, you push the ID to the array. Finally, you store this array in the cookie.

The following code illustrates what it is said above:

```
function saveLightbox(ID){

  $.cookie.json = true;

  var idContainer = ($.cookie('the_cookie')) || [];

  idContainer.indexOf(ID) === -1 && idContainer.push(ID);

  $.cookie('the_cookie', idContainer, { expires: 7 });

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```

}

Another thing to consider, is that once an ID is already stored in the cookie you might want to prevent adding it again, that is the reason for line 4. You can find the working example here: [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/g8XgZ/3/)

Comment: This works as intended. Thanks for the thorough explanation Dago!

Answer (score 0):

save an array and push id's to that array:

```
var ids = $.cookie('the_cookie') || [ ];

function saveLightbox(ID){
  $.cookie('the_cookie', ids.push(ID), { expires: 7 });
  console.debug(ids);
  console.debug($.cookie('the_cookie'));
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify($.cookie('the_cookie'));
}
```

(can't test or demonstrate atm, jsfiddle is not available (for me).)

Comment: Hi DanFromGermany, I tried this but it doesn't output the values when I clicked on the buttons. jsfiddle is still down so I know it's really hard to have a demonstration.

Comment: @user3655840 please see the updated code and in parallel, open your console to see debug messages. You don't see anything because the cookie should hold more than 1 value now.

Comment: The debugger gives me this "ids.push is not a function" and it's still not ouputing anything.